# Display the data from the List using asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="128px" Height="32px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            style="position: relative; top: 3px; left: 4px">
            <asp:ListItem>.......SELECT.......</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Membership</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Publication</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Journal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Additional Activity</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Guide Details</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Project</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Workshop</asp:ListItem>


   //c# code to call the list items
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == Convert.ToInt32(0))
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried for the display of data?

Comment: I have no idea how to start with the code

Comment: From where you will get the list items.Are you taking from Database or hardcoding the items?

Comment: The data present int the list items should be accessed from the database

Comment: @user2660112 the answer below is a beginning, I suggest you research here first of all - there are bound to be a lot of resources to get you started.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(0) <- Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="128px" Height="32px" Style="position: relative;
            top: 3px; left: 4px" >
            <asp:ListItem>.......SELECT.......</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Membership</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Publication</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Journal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Additional Activity</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Guide Details</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Project</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Workshop</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

C#: In button click event you can add the same

```
 protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Membership")// here you can add selectedindex as well
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select columname from tablename where itemanme=Membership", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            gridview1.DataSource=dt; // assign dt to the datasource of grid
            gridview1.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually when i press view button it should display the data.But in this case it is been present inside the dropdownlist function.how to get accessed inside the button..?

Comment: These data should be printed in a grid view...How to print it..?

Comment: Its not being displayed..

Comment: edited now just have a look

Comment: For this code ...should i create a gridview in aspx page..?

Comment: yes..add like this in aspx page: <asp:Gridview id="gridview1" ....></asp:GridView>

Comment: its working and if i need any help i will inform you..

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged event of drpdownlist

```
if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == Convert.ToInt32(0))
    {  
        your display code;
    }
else if(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == Convert.ToInt32(1))
    {  
        your display code;
    }
```

and so on...
 use sqldatareader to display list of records
 for Display records

```
string qry="select * from your table name where youcolumforddl='" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, yourconnection);
        SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.HasRows)
        {
            yourcontrols=dr[0].ToString();
            ....
            ....
            if contorlis int type=Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]);
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: I am new to asp.net.Can youu please suggest me how to display the list of records using sqldatareader.

Comment: I editt the the answer it is a hint use this to write your code

Comment: Thank you...@vikas..But i dont need where condition.i want to display the whole data for the particular emmber

Comment: if you are selecting an item from DropDownList, you need where condition, it is actually find code what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from database or from a collection.
Set the datasource property of the drop down list to that source

```
List<strig> data = // set list from db or from any collection.
DropdownList1.DataSource=data;
DropdownList1.DtataBind();
```

This will load the content from the source to the drop down list.
A source can be any collection.

You can also set the DataTextField and DataValueFiled of the drop down list to specify which property of the collection to be displayed as text and which property of collection as value when drop down item is selected.

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFiled="Name";
DropDownList1.DataValueField="id";
```

Comment: Actually when i press view button it should display the data.But in this case it is been present inside the dropdownlist function.how to get accessed inside the button..?

Comment: What I understand is : You have some items in drop down list. And You have selected one of the item in DDL.  And you have a button to load content. When you click on the button you need to load the content based on the value selected in ddl.  In that vase SelectedValue property of the ddl will give the the selected value.  string x=Dropdownlist1.SelectedValue